# Vue.js css transition on class change

Tags: vue.js, css-transitions

I am trying to use the css transition property to fade the `#app` background from black to white by adding a class of `.lightTheme`. The adding of `.lightTheme` class works as expected, but the transition does not.

Do I have to add the [Vue transition element](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Overview)? And if so how? `#app` is not leaving/entering the dom - I just want to animate it's properties (and I don't want to add unnecessary code if possible!

**HTML**

```
<div id="app" v-bind:class="{ lightTheme: isActive }">
   <button v-on:click="toggleTheme">Change theme</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        isActive: false
    },

    methods: {
      toggleTheme: function(){
          this.isActive = !this.isActive;
        // some code to filter users
      }
    }

});
```

**CSS**

```
#app {
    background: black;
    transition: 1s;
}

#app.lightTheme {
    background: white;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I know this is an older question, but I just faced this issue as well. I want to add that I find it to be bad backwards design by Vue that native browser transitions through class manipulation are effectively disabled. By using Vue we remove native functionality that must be re-introduced by using additional functionality in the framework.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer your question if you have to use transition for something like this, the answer is **no**. The solution you proposed should work out of the box.

There is probably something else that is interfering with your code, but the one you posted is correct.

I attached the working snippet.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        isActive: false
    },
    methods: {
      toggleTheme: function(){
          this.isActive = !this.isActive;
      }
    }
});
```

```css
#app {
    background: black;
    transition: 1s;
}

#app.lightTheme {
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" :class="{ lightTheme: isActive }">
   <button @click="toggleTheme">Change theme</button>
</div>
```